# Keyboard Input Background

Tags: python, pygame, keyboard-events

I've been working in pygame, and I wanted some keyboard input assistance. I tried to put if the a key is pressed, the background would turn red. Unfortunately,it doesn't work.

Perhaps it is because I didn't intend or made a mistake in the syntax?

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
white = (34,34,34)
black=(0,0,0)
red=(255,0,0)
silver=(110,108,108)
yellow=(193,206,104)
yellow2=(213,230,100)
gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))
pygame.display.set_caption('Slither')

gameExit=False

lead_x = 300
lead_y = 300

while not gameExit:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            gameExit = True
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                lead_x -= 10
                print("LEFT")

            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                lead_x +=10
                print("RIGHT")
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                 lead_y -=10
                 print("UP")
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                 lead_y +=10
                 print("DOWN")
            if event.key == pygame.K_a:
                gameDisplay.fill(red)

    gameDisplay.fill(black)
    pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, white,[lead_x,lead_y,30,100])
    pygame.draw.ellipse(gameDisplay, white,[-35+lead_x,-54+lead_y,75,100])
    pygame.draw.ellipse(gameDisplay, red,[-25+lead_x,-35+lead_y,20,34])
    pygame.draw.ellipse(gameDisplay, red,[10+lead_x,-35+lead_y,20,34])
    pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, silver,[470+lead_x,-35+lead_y,75,30])
    pygame.draw.ellipse(gameDisplay, yellow,[400+lead_x,-35+lead_y,75,30])


    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
quit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *are* filling the screen with red, but once the `for` loop ends, you paint over it with black before the display updates. Rather than directly caling `fill` inside the `if`, you could make the changes persistent by instead updating a `background_color` variable with the new color, and using that as the fill color once the event loop finishes.

```
#snip
background_color = black
while not gameExit:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            gameExit = True
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            #snip
            if event.key == pygame.K_a:
                background_color = red

    gameDisplay.fill(background_color)
    pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, white,[lead_x,lead_y,30,100])
    #snip
```